# Angular - How to refresh main page when modal when modal form is submitted

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

In Angular-14, I am using ngx-bootstrap-modal for my project.

I have this code:

```
onMerchantSubmitForm() {
 this.isSubmitted = true;
 if (this.createMerchantForm.invalid) {
  return;
}
this.isLoading = true;

const formData = this.createMerchantForm.value;

this.merchantService.createMerchant(formData).subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => {
    this.toastr.success(res.message);
    this.isLoading = false;
    window.location.reload();
    this.onClose();
  },
  error: (error) => {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    }
    this.toastr.error(errorMessage);
    this.isLoading = false;
    }
 })
}
```

When user submits the modal form, I it is expected the the main page is reloaded (using window.location.reload()).

This is working fine on the local. But when I deployed, whenever the user submits the modal form the application reloads the Login Page instead of the main page of the modal form.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ngBootstrap modal?

Comment: @Ayobamilaye problem is due to authguard redirecting you to login!

Comment: @Aniket - I am using ngx-bootstrap modal

Comment: @NarenMurali - Yes, I used authguard, but that when there's issue. The modal form successfully inserted data into the DB. So it shouldn't happen. The application is not behaving like that on modal. This only happens on production

Answer (score 0):

Use this code as reference in the parent component.

```
 this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ComponentHere);
    this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
        console.log('results', result);
    })
```